# Inserting new key/value pair in std::unordered_map causes an "out of range" exception

Tags: c++, hashmap, hashtable

I'm working on Leetcode challenges and I want to utilize a hashtable or `std::unordered_map` to store values after each iteration. Based on what I've read, it should be as simple as saying `hash[key] = value`. However, the Leetcode compiler throws out a `std::out_of_range` exception from `_Map_base::at()`.

Here's my code:

```
#include <unordered_map>

class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        std::unordered_map<int,int> hashMap;
        vector<int> result;
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
        {
            if(hashMap.count(target-nums[i]) > 0)
            {
                result.push_back(hashMap.at(target-nums[i]));
                result.push_back(hashMap.at(nums[i]));
            }
            else
                hashMap[nums[i]] = i;
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

Comment: Why do you assume there is an entry for nums[i] after checking if there is one for target-nums[i]?

Comment: I don't assume, I'm checking. I basically want to see if the [target-current value] is stored in the hashMap. I fully expect there to be nothing in the first iteration, so if it's not there, then use hashMap[nums[i]] = i to store the key as a value and index as a value to the map.

Comment: I recommend you to learn how to use a *debugger*. With a good *debugger*, you will be able to step through your code line by line and inspect the values of your variables. It will make spotting and inspecting the error much easier. *Debugging* is something you should do **before** asking a question here.

Comment: I fear you misunderstood my comment. I see that you do check for target-nums[i]. After this check succeeds, however, you not only access the element you checked for but also the element at nums[i](which you have not checked). You assume that (target-nums[i] exists) implies (nums[i] exists). I dont think that assumption is justified

Comment: Wow, what a simple mistake. I see now. It's a shame that the leetcode debugger couldn't give more info. Thanks though.

Comment: @Fureeish I'm doing these challangers on a web browser. Next time I run into issues like that, I'll replicate the code onto visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        std::unordered_map<int,int> hashMap;
        vector<int> result;
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
        {
            if(hashMap.find(target-nums[i])!=hashMap.end())
            {
                result.push_back(hashMap.at(target-nums[i]));
                result.push_back(hashMap.at(nums[i]));
            }
            else
                hashMap.insert(pair(nums[i],i));
                //or You case also write hashMap[nums[i]] = i;
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

This line throws an exception the with value is not present

```
if(hashMap.count(target-nums[i]) > 0)
```

The right way of checking if the key exists in the unordered_map is using `.find()` method.